# Cannot do push / pull in git - working with visual studio

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, github

I have made a lot of changes, when I am trying to push them - I am getting the next error:

**You cannot push branch master to remote origin because there are new commits in the remote repository’s branch. Pushing this branch would result in a non-fast-forward update on the branch in the remote repository.**

When I am trying to pull the changes I get:

**Cannot pull because there are uncommitted changes. Commit or undo your changes before pulling again. See the Output window for details.**

I dont have any uncommitted changes...

I am stock from both ways and dont know how solve this issue.

*not long ago I run the command:  git rm --cached in order to solve a git ignore issue. could be it is connected?

Comment: What version of VS?  What does `git status` say?  What are your line ending configurations like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this procedure:

stash your local commits Try to get the changes and then push:

```
$ git stash
```

pull from master:

```
$ git pull
```

get your local changes back after pulling the master branch

```
$ git stash pop
```

commit your local changes

```
$ git commit
```

push

```
$ git push
```