# Unable to do Push in Visual Studio after commit

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, github, bitbucket

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and Bitbucket extension to connect with my Bitbucket branch of code.
I've performed following operations:-

1) Created a new local branch of my Bitbucket branch
[image]

2) I've modified my code and then I went to the "Changes" page

3) I've enter the comments and then click "Commit and Push"

4) The commit happens to the local repository but "Push" genreates as error:

**You cannot push branch Test_Branch to remote origin because there are new commits in the remote repository’s branch. Pushing this branch would result in a non-fast-forward update on the branch in the remote repository.**

Can anyone please suggest, how to resolve this error and push the changes to the Bitbucket branch?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot do push / pull in git - working with visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39063390/cannot-do-push-pull-in-git-working-with-visual-studio)

Comment: @SamuelDion-Girardeau No its not a duplicate. I've asked for a solution possible with Visual Studio and Bitbucket extension and the solution doesn't provide any reference for that.

Comment: Try pulling first?

Comment: @ASHISH_TECHIT This is the same error you will get with GitHub, BitBucket, GitLab, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common error in Git, and it simply means that since you have synched your local branch with the remote version, someone else has made commits on top of that remote branch.  The error message is saying that it can't simply play your commits on top of the remote branch.

The typical fix here is to just `git pull`.  In Visual Studio you would do a sync operation, with a pull as well.  Once you have done this, you should be able to push, and the error message should go away.

Follow the link below for instructions on how to pull from Visual Studio.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/tutorial/pulling?view=vsts&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: I tried using "Sync" operation from Visual Studio to Sync and pull the branch but received error: 
Error encountered while fetching: An error occurred while sending the request.Inner Exception:
    The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.

Comment: Then you have some other connection problem.  This isn't related to your original question though, and I would like to avoid a discussion festival with you in comments.  Fix your connection, then try my answer.